# DirectX11 2 window rendering

Tags: c++, directx-11

How can I render my objects with DirectX into 2 separated windows?

Comment: If you want to answer your own question, you should write an actual answer instead of putting the answer in the question.

Comment: Okay sorry ... I'll remember that

Comment: No need to be sorry, I was just pointing it out.

Comment: @Quest That's nice you'll remember that, but you should do that for this question, like right now. Move the answer into an answer and accept it, and change the question part to actually have a well worded question.  Otherwise this feels incomplete, and I don't want to upvote a topic with poor formatting like this.  Actually, I'm inclined to downvote and flag it unless this is done.

Comment: @Quest I hope my comment didn't sound harsh.  Thanks for following through! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create one SwapChain and RenderTargetView for every window.

1 if you created your device via CreateDeviceAndSwapChain you need to obtain IDXGIFactory first

```
IDXGIDevice * device;
d3ddevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice), (void**)&device);

IDXGIAdapter * adapter;
device->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIAdapter), (void**)&adapter);

IDXGIFactory * factory;
adapter->GetParent(__uuidof(DDXGIFactory), (void**)&factory);
```

With DXGIFactory you can create additional swapchain for new window

```
factory->CreateSwapChain(g_pd3dDevice, &sd, &g_pSwapChain2);
```

then create a render target view

```
ID3D11Texture2D* pBackBuffer = NULL;
hr = g_pSwapChain2->GetBuffer( 0, __uuidof( ID3D11Texture2D ), ( LPVOID* )&pBackBuffer );
if( FAILED( hr ) )
    return hr;

hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateRenderTargetView( pBackBuffer, NULL, &g_pRenderTargetView );
pBackBuffer->Release();
if( FAILED( hr ) )
    return hr;
```

And finally just set your render target(s) and Draw something!

```
g_immediateContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &g_RenderTargetView, NULL);
....
```

I hope this has been helpful.

Best regards Quest :)