# Best way to render in multiple windows using DirectX11

Tags: directx, directx-11

I am a newbie in DirectX and currently learning `DirectX11`. I have been assigned a task where I have to render our graphics in multiple windows (each window with it's own HWND), usually two(say `Window1` and `Window2`).

What is the most efficient way to implement this ?
We are using onboard `Intel 4600 HD`. It's not a fancy chip but gets the job done. Would appreciate some insights into this multiple window rendering.

The hardware we are using has two video outputs. We connect two physical displays (`Display1` and `Display2`) to these outputs and each window is then rendered in it's physical display.

That is, `Window1` will be rendered on `Display1` and `Window2` will be rendered on `Display2`.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292996/directx11-2-window-rendering) might be helpful. You could also render the scene to a larger texture (total size of your windows) and just present the correct piece of the textures to the right screen. That would avoid duplicating the draw calls for each screen.

Comment: @NicoSchertler thanks for your response.the link is useful.